# How to log exception stack traces in Jetty?

Tags: java, exception, jetty, jetty-8

When a servlet throws a NullPointerException, only the name of the exception is logged on the stderr. (When it's a ServerletException, the stacktrace is logged).

How to enable logging the stacktrace of all exceptions in Jetty 8 ? I'm using Debian's jetty8 package.

Answer (score 1):

See `STACKS` property in the logging config: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Jetty_Logging

Comment: https://archive.eclipse.org/jetty/wiki/Jetty/Feature/Jetty%20Logging.html